# Google Chrome suddenly stops loading any pages (but other browsers are fine)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

On a Windows 10 laptop, Google Chrome has suddenly stopped opening any websites. It *does* load the start-up page (Google logo and search box) rather than show "no internet". But it won't even load our local http://192.168.1.1 page for the router.

We just get a seemingly infinite loading spinny wheel - we've left it for up to 20 minutes. It doesn't appear to time out it just sits there.

By contrast Edge on the same laptop has no issues. I had heard Edge has updated recently so I wonder if this or some other Windows update could be to blame? We can't find others having the same problem or how to diagnose further but rely on Google sync between devices so switching browser is really not a preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue with my W10 laptop. The only way to "solve" the problem is to close the browser and then open the task manager (Google Chrome task does not ends when new tabs stops to work and you closes the browser) then you end GC task and when you open it again new tabs start to work again. In my case, this method is just temporary. After a few minutes or tabs opened the issue starts again. I'm clueless about the definitive solution for this problem.